# Reading from txt file with varable name in txt file

Tags: c++, txt

I was just wondering how you assign variable from a text file when your text file looks like

```
"Variable name a"  1.0
"Variable name b"  2.0
"Variable name c"  3.0
```

etc.

I am just trying to assign the values without it erroring out due to the variable names in the text document.

I have tried contacting my professor but he is sick and hasn't been checking his email.

Comment: the next variable is in a new row, idk stackoverflow formatted it like that

Comment: The name of a variable is not data; it only exists in the source code. If you want a mapping between names and objects you need to manage it yourself, using conditionals or tables.

Comment: BTW: please be more specific than "erroring out". Nobody has any idea what you mean, and it's impossible to guess what's wrong with invisible code.

Answer (score 2):

Oops... There a major misunderstanding here. C++ is not a dynamic language where it is possible to declare a new variable along with its name. Producing an executable requires different steps(*):

- you first compile source files. The variable names only make sense in that phase. In any of the following phases only the names may have been replaced by any *keys*, generally relative or absolute addresses
- then you link the compiled files and the required libraries to build a true executable
- finally you execute your program

Long story made short, you do not want to create new variables. But you can store new values in containers like a `map` or `unordered_map` and index them with a string...

---

(*) this is just a simplified view. In a real world environment, the compilation is splitted in a precompilation then actual compilation, and the link phase can be splitted in a static link phase (at build time) and a dynamic link phase (just before run time)

Answer (score 0):

Du to C++ beeing a compiled language you cannot create Variables at runtime. As a Workaround you could create a array/map with the index beeing the variable name. Then you clould call the

`array[variablename]`

an get the value

Answer (score 0):

You will need an associative container to associate a name with the value.  I recommend `std::map`.

```
std::map<string, int> database;
std::string row_text;
while (std::getline(my_file, row_text)
{
  char first_double_quotes;
  std::istringstream row_stream(row_text);
  row_stream >> first_double_quotes;
  std::string variable_name;
  std::getline(row_stream, variable_name, '"');
  int value;
  std::row_stream >> value;
  database[variable_name] = value;
}
```

To retrieve the value of the variable:

```
int variable_value = database[variable_name];
```

In C++ you can't create named variables on the fly (at runtime).  However, you can put names into an associative container and treat the slot like a variable.